# C# Lotus Notes - Sent mail is not in

Tags: c#, email, lotus-notes, lotus

I'm sending mails from C# using Lotus Notes, but the sent mails are not in the database and can not be seen in the output folder.

My code is:

```
_notesSession = new NotesSession();
string sPassword = "";
_notesSession.Initialize(sPassword);
string sServer = "";
string sFile = "data\mailfilename.nsf";
_notesDataBase=_notesSession.GetDatabase(sServer, sFile, false);
// not: _notesDataBase=_notesSession(GetDatabase(sServer, sFile, false));
if (!_notesDataBase.IsOpen) _notesDataBase.Open();
_notesDocument = _notesDataBase.CreateDocument();
_notesDocument.SaveMessageOnSend = true;
.
.
.
_notesDocument.Save(true,false);
_ItemValue = _notesDocument.GetItemValue("SendTo");
_notesDocument.Send(false, ref _ItemValue);
```

If I check the value of _notesDocument before sending the mail, I see the following error message after CreateDocument():

FolderReferences = "((Domino.NotesDocumentClass)(_notesDocument)).FolderReferences" hat eine Ausnahme vom Typ "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException" verursacht.
(... has caused an exception with type of...)
base {System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException} = {"Folder References are not enabled on the database"}

BTW I also tried to replace the sFile with the fully qualified path (c:....nsf), but the result is the same.

Can anybody give me a hint, what to do to save the mail in the output folder?

Comment: I don't know what your configuration looks like, but normally "data" is the root of the file tree for Lotus Notes database, and it would not be included in a relative file path, so insted of "data\mailfilename.nsf", it would just be "mailfilename.nsf", or maybe "mail\filename.nsf".

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "the output folder".  The normal location for sent mail in Lotus Notes is the Sent view.  (A view is not the same thing as a folder.)

Answer (score 0):

This line strikes me as odd:

```
_notesDataBase=_notesSession(GetDatabase(sServer, sFile, false));
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
_notesDataBase= _notesSession.GetDatabase(sServer, sFile, false);
```

Comment: The second one is the one I use. I filled it in here in a worg way.
An I correct it in my question. -sorry-